# Apply css on all blog

Tags: css

I want to add custom CSS on all SharePoint Blog.

I don't want to add webpart with css one by one.

Do you have solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to issues here: adding the custom CSS to new sites created from the Blog template and adding it on the already existing sites.

The first one is actually quite easy. You need to use [Feature Stapling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544294.aspx). 
The basic idea is the following:

- Build a feature that adds in your CSS on the web site using the technique you prefer (for example using a custom action/delegate control registration, a custom master page and so on)
- Add a second "**stapler**" feature that attaches the first feature to the template you need to have it activated on (i.e: the blog template)

Creating the stapler is quite simple too. You just need to create a new feature and in the element file add a line defining the stapling association. For example:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
      TemplateName="STS#0" />
</Elements>
```

would automatically activate the specified feature on all new sites created from the "STS#0" template.

**But...** this would still leave you with a problem. Your feature wouldn't get activated on any already-existing blog. Sadly, I don't think you are left with many options here.
Modifying the out of box blog template so to include the CSS could probably work, but it is not something Microsoft supports and will potentialy left you open to problems and bugs when a new update/service pack comes in.
The only thing I can think off is building a simple comand line application / PowerShell script that would enumerate all the sites in the farm, check which template they are built on and then activate the same feature you created for the stapler as needed.